# Flutter beamer routing package causes rebuilding the previous screen when using beamBack method

Tags: flutter, flutter-beamer

I am using `beamer` routing package for my flutter project. When calling `Beamer.of(context).beamBack();`, it causes rebuilding the previous page in the navigation stack.

For example, there are two screens, **ScreenA** and **ScreenB**. Initially navigated from ScreenA to ScreenB, then using `beamBack` method from ScreenB causes ScreenA rebuilds. How can i avoid rebuilding?

Comment: Have you set correctly the `key` property in the BeamPage of `ScreenA`. It's important in beamer set it up correctly https://pub.dev/packages/beamer#page-keys